# Loop breaks during iteration: Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code which searches a column of a data frame and returns a value if the requirement is met:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("cl.csv")
count=0
print(len(df.sl_no))
print(len(df.sn_compare))
for i in range(len(df.sn_compare)):
    if df.sn_compare[i] in df.sl_no:
        print(df.margin[i])
        count=count+1

print(count)
```

Output:

```
8258
8258
0.036621541
.
.
.
0.036621541
0.043934426
0.063724333
3770
```

Why does the loop stop after reaching 3770, when ideally I wanted it to search for all the 8259 rows?

Comment: Maybe because only `3770` entries from `df.sn_compare` are in `df.sl_no`?

Comment: You only raise your counter variable when the condifiton is met. So the condition is met 3770 times. He is still searching everything. Place the count=count+1 in the line above the if-statement and check the result.

Comment: You're only adding 1 to `count` if `df.sn_compare[i] in df.sl_no`

Comment: `count` is only increased when your `if` condition evaluates to `True`; which is apparently not always the case.

Comment: de-indent the `count = count + 1` and run it again. you shall see

Comment: The loop runs for 8259 rows but there are only 3770 matches. In reality, the matches are around 5000.

Comment: @RishabhKumar How do you know it's roughly 5000 matches? Is it exact matches after trimming? What about lower/upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following example (*I did not add margin column though*). However for the `for` loop, it checks if column value contains in other columns values, so added `.values` (*I don't know if it would be same case but in this case if I don't then, it will return 0*).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sl_no':[1,2,3], 'sn_compare':[4,5,3]})
print(df)
```

Output of `df`:

```
     sl_no  sn_compare
0      1           4
1      2           5
2      3           3
```

Now,

```
print(len(df.sl_no))
print(len(df.sn_compare))
count=0

for i in range(len(df.sn_compare)):
    if df.sn_compare[i] in df.sl_no.values:
        #print(df.margin[i])
        count=count+1

print('Count is: ', count)
```

Output:

```
3
3
Count is:  1
```

Output for count would be `1` since only `3` matches so, the `count` becomes 1.

Comment: I placed the count in the loop because I want to count the number of times the condition is met. The problem is that count should ideally report a number around 5000.

Comment: @RishabhKumar will it help if you use `.values` in comparison? i.e. `if df.sn_compare[i] in df.sl_no.values:`

Comment: Thanks, df.sl_no.values sorted my issue.

Comment: @RishabhKumar Great! you can accept the answer if you would like. `Happy Coding.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only incrementing your counter variable when the condition is met. That means that your result of 3770 means that the condition is met 3770 times. It doesn't say anything about the amount of rows that were searched. Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("cl.csv")
count=0
print(len(df.sl_no))
print(len(df.sn_compare))
for i in range(len(df.sn_compare)):
    if df.sn_compare[i] in df.sl_no:
        print(df.margin[i])
    count=count+1

print(count)
```

The difference is that the increment of your counter variable has a different indentation. It is outside of the comparison and is therefore executed for every row.

Comment: I placed the count in the loop because I want to count the number of times the condition is met. The problem is that count should ideally report a number around 5000.

Comment: @RishabhKumar That's important information that should be edited into your question. Currently you only say "Why does the loop stop after reaching 3770, when ideally I wanted it to search for all the 8259 rows?" and the answer to that is that it doesn't seem to stop and searches all the rows.